# SimpleAdapter retrieve String

Tags: android, simpleadapter

I have a SimpleAdapter with only 2 Textviews populating a list.I would like to retrieve one of these textview strings onListItemClicked().
 I can get an

```
Object o = adapter.getItem(position);
```

But I would like the String?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the `onListItemClicked` callback is a `View` representing that row. You could use that row to search for the desired `TextView` and obtain the `String` from that:

```
TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.the_desired_textview_id);
String str = txt.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are assigning values from main acivity store the values in map
foe ex

```
map.put("VALUE", country_name);
```

and to retrive the string value from adapter class use this in adapter

```
System.out.println("NAME" + item.get("VALUE"));
```

Comment: So are you saying that the object returned by `adapter.getItem(position)` is a map?